# mouse event error on touch screen when using leaflet map with lightning component

Tags: lightning, mobile, event, touch

I created lightning component for a map, Im using Leaflet library to display map and points on it , on desktop ( mouse devices) it works well ( click, pan, zoom ), but on touch screen it does not work
when I open the map on real ipad, I have this error message:

> TypeError:Can only call MouseEvent.initMouseEvent on instances of
>   MouseEvent throws at https://{my
>    domin}.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/rNSAVNTno4PUWiQm9PXAFg/aura_prod_compat.js:825:143

when I open it on chrome ipad simulation , I have this error message : (it was lightning App)

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation throws at
>   https://{my domin}.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/rNSAVNTno4PUWiQm9PXAFg/aura_prod.js:824:138

I dont think it is leaflet issue because leaflet examples on their website works fine on mobile

please help

Comment: can you post your code here

Comment: code does not have anything about mouse interaction, these mouse events for  map point click and map pan are default in leaflet library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
add this option to map object:
tap:false

```
  map =  L.map(mapElem,{tap:false});
```

and it will be solved, because it seems there is a conflict between tap implementation in leaflet and tap (click) implementation in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, too. Many thanks.
I added `tap:false` into the map `initialisation`:

```
var map = L.map(mapDiv, {zoomControl: false, tap:false}).setView([51.506246, -0.086292], 14);
```